# Blocky VDB artefacts when combine with principle volume?

Tags: volumetrics

I notice when i have a VDB volumetric sequence inside a standard blender principle volume setup, this renders with large blocky artefacts that only appear when the principle volume is enabled. Ie if i render the VDB by itself, its fine, no blocky artefacts.

Anyone experience this?

I'm using Embergen to generate the VDB, however ive seen this with other sequences from Houdini. Its not a resolution issue. Like i say above, works fine when rendering the VDB by itself.

Rendering with Cycles.

It seems like layering multiple atmospheric systems over each other causes this issue maybe.

Thank you!
David

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by rendering the "VDB by itself"? For rendering you need a material, if it is not the _Principled Volume_ (as this is the blocky one), what are you using to render instead? And would it be asked too much if you would provide any screenshots? Maybe of the blocky version, the fine version, the material setup...

Comment: Is it to do with your render-sampling rate in _Cycles > Volume_ settings, or _EEVEE > Volumetrics_ settings ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! VDB by itself;  I mean if i disable the principle volume cube i have in the scene providing general atmospherics. There's currently two atmospheric systems; the standard cube with a principle volume shader applied, and a VDB sequence with a principle volume shader applied. If i disable the cube system, the the VDB renders without blocky effect. Hm, how do i add an image here?

Comment: ![Image](https://ibb.co/qCD0pcZ).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcBsBWtyi4g